# Reduce top margin and add some text in header and footer

Tags: margins

Question: 1 I want to start my starting text exact below the top rule i mean how can i reduce margin between first line and top line?

Question: 2 How can i add some text on the top line and below the bottom line? Even i want page numbers on right of the top.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0.70in, right=0.70in, top=0.70in, bottom=0.70in]{geometry}
%page style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\begin{document}
Starting of the document
\end{document}
```

Comment: Specify the stuff you want with the macros provided by the `fancyhdr` package e.g. `\fancyhf[rh]{\thepage}` or whatever. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Would you please explain?

Comment: I just did. I gave you an example. There are plenty more in the manual. I don't know what the question is. You just haven't specified any headers or footers: specify them and they will appear. That's all there is to it. Above and below the line is where these things normally go: it's the default.

Comment: Sorry for that, Question is i want some text in left head, right head which will appear on the header line. Similarly for footer line

Comment: Second question was i want to decrease the blank space between the header line and beginning of the first line

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers i would recommend scrlayer-scrpage further down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there should be no space between the top rule and the text body use `headsep=0pt` as option for `geometry`. But the result looks strange ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=0.70in, right=0.70in, top=0.70in, bottom=0.70in,
  headsep=0pt,% remove space between header and text body
  headheight=17pt% suggested by fancyhdr
  ]{geometry}
%page style
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% remove the default header and footer entries
\fancyhead[L]{left header entry}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{left footer entry}
\fancyfoot[R]{right footer entry}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\begin{document}
Starting of the document 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What would be ideal line spacing?